# How to subtract arrays of integers

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have four arrays of int:

```
num_defect = [30, 30, 20, 20, 18, 18, 5, 5]
num_fixes = [1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]
num_blocks = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0]
num_ext_defects = [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

I want to display the number of open defects, which is given by:

```
num_defects - num_fixes - num_blocks - num_ext_defects
```

So for the reporting, `num_defects` should now contain:
`[28, 29, 17, 13, 12, 0, 2]`

I tried:

```
num_defect.map { |i| i - num_fixes[i] - num_blocks[i] - num_ext_defects[i] }
```

but it raises:

> nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are `num_defect[1..10]`, etc.? Do you mean you have four variables `num_defect`, etc.? And are you sure you want to do subtraction `num_defects - num_fixes - num_blocks - num_ext_defects`? Subtraction of array gives you the elements that are present int he first array and absent in the second.

Comment: Perhaps it is a better idea to give the (simplified) contents of the arrays you have, and the expected result.

Comment: +1, don't try to make your questions too abstract, give us concrete input, concrete output and explain what you want to happen in between.

Comment: I have edited my question and given real examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
num_defect.map { |i|
```

`i` is the element of the array, not its index. If you want your `map` to work correctly, you'll need an index as well:

```
num_defect.map.with_index do |element, index|
  element - num_fixes[index] - num_blocks[index] - num_ext_defects[index]
end
```

Use `map!` instead of `map` in order to mutate `num_defect`.

Or if you'd like a nicer version:

```
a = [30,30,20,20,18,18,5,5]
b = [ 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2,2,2]
c = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2,1,0]
d = [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2,2,1]

a.zip(b,c,d).map { |arr| arr.inject(:-) }
#  => [28, 29, 17, 18, 13, 12, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Yes, zip is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Marcin!
The first example for works and I am using `map!` as I need to mutate `num_defect`.
The nicer version however does not work when using `map!` and I need that mutation.

Comment: Or `[a,b,c,d].transpose.map{|ar| ar.inject(:-) }`

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you might be looking for an array method called ***each_index***.

```
num_defect.each_index do |i|
   num_defect[i] -= num_fixes[i] + num_blocks[i] + num_ext_defects[i]
end
```

Comment: IN this case, your code modify the original `num_defect` variable.

Comment: @LukasBaliak to be totally fair, the original question mentions `So for the reporting, num_defects should now contain` which does make it sound like mutation is desired.

Comment: Looking at his explenation that's what he wanted to achieve

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej you are right, but its bad patern and the question contains two variables `num_defects` and `num_defect`. Ofc this could be a typo error.

Comment: "num_defects" with the trailing "s" was a typo.

Comment: A small suggestion: when you reference a method give a link to its doc: "...you might be looking for the method [Array#each_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each_index)".

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'matrix'

(Vector.elements(num_defect) - Vector.elements(num_fixes) -
 Vector.elements(num_blocks) - Vector.elements(num_ext_defects)).to_a
  #=> [28, 29, 17, 18, 13, 12, 0, 2]
```

This uses the methods [Vector::elements](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-c-elements) and [Vector#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-to_s). One could write `Vector[*arr]` in place of `Vector.elements(arr)`, using [Vector::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-c-5B-5D).

If `num_defect` is to be mutated, you could write `num_defect.replace(<above expression>)`. If

```
arr = [num_defect, num_fixes, num_blocks, num_ext_defects]
  #=> [[30, 30, 20, 20, 18, 18, 5, 5],
  #    [ 1,  0,  3,  2,  1,  2, 2, 2],
  #    [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  2, 1, 0],
  #    [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  2,  2, 2, 1]]
```

one could use matrix multiplication:

```
(Matrix.row_vector([1, *[-1]*(arr.size-1)]) * Matrix.rows(arr)).to_a.first
  #=> [28, 29, 17, 18, 13, 12, 0, 2]
```

where

```
[1, *[-1]*(arr.size-1)]
  #=> [1, -1, -1, -1]
```

This would be convenient and relatively computationally-efficient if `arr` had a larger number of elements than it does in the example.

This uses the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) methods [Matrix::row_vector](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-row_vector), [Matrix::rows](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-rows) and [Matrix#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-to_a). One could write `Matrix[*arr]` in place of `Matrix.rows(arr)`, using [Matrix::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-5B-5D). One advantage of using `rows`, however, is that one can add the argument `false` (`Matrix.rows(arr, false)`) to avoid copying the elements of `arr` in the creation of the `Matrix` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
[num_defect, num_fixes, num_blocks, num_ext_defects]
.transpose
.map{|first, *rest| first - rest.sum}
# => [28, 29, 17, 18, 13, 12, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Enumerator#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
num_defect.each_with_index.with_object([]){ |(e, i), a| a << (e  - num_fixes[i] - num_blocks[i] - num_ext_defects[i]) }
#=> [28, 29, 17, 18, 13, 12, 0, 2]
```